# Is the set of Gödel numbers of computable constant functions recursively enumerable?

Tags: computability, semi-decidability

I've been working on the following exercise:

> $S = \{ x | f_x  \text{ is constant} \}$. Is $S$ recursively enumerable?

Here, $fx$ is the function computed by the $\text{x-th TM}$. So it is a computable function.

---

**Intuitively**, I think that to check if $S$ is constant, I would have to check if $f_x$ stops for every input. That procedure would run forever.

**Important:** Same thing about $\overline{S}$, if some $f_x$ is undefined for every input $y$ (it would not be constant, as far as I understand, **it is constant if it has the same image for all input values**) then I would not be able to list $f_x$ in an enumeration of $\overline{S}$.

In fact, suppose $\forall x,fx$ is undefined. This $f_x$ is computable - a TM can be constructed that loops forever. How can you determine that $f_x$ is not constant? There will be no input for which $f_x$ halts. Therefore, we cannot check for equality of $x_1$ and $x_2$ to determine that is not constant. Then, we can't list this $TM_x$ in the enumeration.

A solution in which this $f_x$ was put at the beginning of the enumeration was suggested. But there are infinitely many $TMs$ that are undefined for all inputs. Consequently, I can't put them at the beginning of the enumeration as other $TMs$ won't be enumerated.

---

**I tried to** reduce the *Halting Problem* to this problem without success. I believe that both $S$ and $\overline{S}$ are not r.e. (see my intuitive thoughts above).

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: At which points specifically are you not 100% certain about your attempt? It's mathematics; you can check every step yourself until you hit a problem. Also, you seem to missing one step: in order to contradict undecidability of the halting problem, you need to construct a test for whether $f_x(x)$ holds for *input* $x$, not a fixed one.

Comment: @Vor Please see my question edited above. I described why your proposed solution in a comment may not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is good: checking whether $x \in S$ is stronger than checking $x \in K$ ($K$ the halting problem, i.e. $K = \{ x \mid f_x(x) \text{ halts}\}$). In other words,

$\qquad\displaystyle \langle \operatorname{sgn} \circ f\rangle \in S \implies f \in K$.

However, the reverse does not hold and no similar implication works for $\overline{K}$, the reduction partner we really want (as it's not semi-decidable).

---

A small interlude: the title you chose does not actually fit the question! The set of all constant functions *is* in fact recursively enumerable, e.g. by

$\qquad\displaystyle \varphi_i(x) = i$

which is clearly a computable function. Many sets of functions are enumerable like this, [but not all](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/266/why-are-the-total-functions-not-enumerable).

What you are really asking is: given a [Gödel numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering) (e.g. an encoding of all Turing machines), what about the set of all *indices* (read: programs) that compute this here set of functions? That's another thing entirely because of the properties such a Gödel numbering has. The distinction is important, see e.g. [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2811/98).

---

The basic idea for a reduction is always this: build a function that depends on $x$ and whose encoding is in $S$ if and only if $x \in \overline{K}$ -- then we got a deal.

So, consider

$\qquad\displaystyle g_x(n) = 
    \begin{cases}
        n, &f_x(x) \text{ halts after at most $n$ steps } \\
        1, &\text{else}
    \end{cases}
$

which is clearly computable. Note furthermore that given $x$, we can compute $y$ with $f_y = g_x$; such compilation is possible because we have (or can assume) a Gödel numbering. Now, clearly

$\qquad \langle g_x \rangle \in S \iff x \in \overline{K}$

holds; thus $S$ can't be semi-decidable since $\overline{K}$ would then be semi-decidable, too, contradicting what we know.

Comment: I've seen that construction of 'if it halts after at most steps then something else something' many times now. Is it usually useful? Is it a common method? I mean, it may have a proper name. If it does, could you point me to a reading?

Comment: It comes up in different places in theory (also complexity theory) but I don't know of a name. There may be one, though; maybe ask a [tag:terminology] question?