# Why is set of Turing machine set DD = {⟨M⟩ | ⟨M⟩⟨M⟩ not in L(M)} not decidable?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability

To prove that the set $\mathrm{DIAG} = \{\langle M\rangle \mid \langle M\rangle \notin L(M)\}$ is not decidable, we can assume, to the contrary, that there is a Turing Machine $M$ such that $L(M) = \mathrm{DIAG}$. Consider the string $\langle M\rangle$. By definition of $\mathrm{DIAG}$, $\langle M\rangle \in \mathrm{DIAG} \Leftrightarrow \langle M\rangle \notin L(M)$. But since $L(M) = \mathrm{DIAG}, \langle M\rangle \notin L(M) \Leftrightarrow \langle M\rangle \notin \mathrm{DIAG}$. So $\langle M\rangle \in \mathrm{DIAG} \Leftrightarrow \langle M\rangle \notin \mathrm{DIAG}$, which is impossible.

I don't know how to extend this proof to prove that $DD = \{\langle M\rangle \mid \langle M\rangle\langle M\rangle \notin L(M)\}$ is not decidable. Can someone show how to do this?

Comment: Can you can apply rice's theorem?

Comment: @DanielSaad Why give a misleading hint? Rive's theorem doesn't apply here.

Comment: @Raphael Why  Rice's Theorem can't be applied here? The predicate isn't a non-trivial property? You should be more careful with your words, even if I'm wrong I was trying to help. It was neither an answer, nor  a misleading tip, It was a question. Please be more polite.

Comment: @DanielSaad Neither DIAG nor DD are index sets. See e.g. [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2812/98) and [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/84951/98). (It's nice that you're trying to help, but you should make sure you know the material yourself beforehand. Even though your comment is grammatically a question, how could it be read but as a hint?)

Comment: What I am thinking is construct some language which contains halt which can be reduced from Diag, and then try to reduce it to DD, but I can not reduce it to DD.

Comment: Must the diagonal method be used? Or you just wonder how to prove $\mathrm{DD}$ is not decidable?